# Erro ao fazer count no join

Tags: sql, join, count

Estou tendo dificuldades em uma questão na qual meus códigos sempre dão errado.

A questão é: Selecione o nome do cliente e a quantidade de telefones que estes têm cadastrados classificados em ordem decrescente pela quantidade de telefones.

Meu código:

```
SELECT DISTINCT clientes.nome ,COUNT(clientes_telefone.telefone) as telefones
from clientes
join clientes_telefone
ON clientes.codigo = clientes_telefone.cliente
Order BY telefone DESC;
```

Achei que o código acima estaria certo mas, ele mostra:

| Nome | Telefone |
| --- | --- |
| Brigite | 5 |

Queria que aparecessem todos os nomes e a quantidade de celulares, mas ao colocar o `count`, tudo fica aglomerado na Brigite.

Comment: Acho que está faltando o Group By na sua consulta, e o Distinct não será necessário

Answer (score 2):

Você deve se atentar a dois detalhes na sua *Query*:

1. Conforme comentado, o `DISTINCT` não é necessário; você deve substituir sua ideia por um `GROUP BY clientes.nome` para agregar os dados antes da ordenação;
2. Na cláusula `Order By`, você está chamando a coluna "telefone", e não a contagem `COUNT(clientes_telefone.telefone) as telefones` (note que esta está no plural).

Reescrevendo sua query, ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT DISTINCT clientes.nome ,COUNT(clientes_telefone.telefone) as telefones
from clientes join clientes_telefone ON clientes.codigo = clientes_telefone.cliente
GROUP BY clientes.nome
ORDER BY telefones
```